# .Net Core 3.1 - Mutiple hosted services with independent configurations

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, ihostedservice

As far I know, it's possible to add multiple hosted services to run under the same 'host', like this example took from Microsoft [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice):

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Other DI registrations;

    // Register Hosted Services
    services.AddHostedService<GracePeriodManagerService>();
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedServiceB>();
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedServiceC>();
    //...
}
```

If instead of that I create three different projects, It would be possible to inject three different configurations for each one of them.

Is there any way to do that in same project? Maybe loading different configuration files(appsettings.json)?

Like:

- For hosted service **GracePeriodManagerService** *appsettings.graceperiod.json*
- For hosted service **MyHostedServiceB** *appsettings.myHostedServiceB.json*

Or separating it by folders:

- For hosted service **GracePeriodManagerService** *GracePeriodManagerService\appsettings.json*
- For hosted service **MyHostedServiceB** *MyHostedServiceB\appsettings.json*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

The best way would be to use [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) pattern:
In your appsettings file you can add:

```
"Position": {
    "Title": "Editor",
    "Name": "Joe Smith"
  }
```

You should have a class matching the json object above:

```
public class PositionOptions

{
    public const string Position = "Position";

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally you can inject it to the DI container by:

```
services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(
                                        PositionOptions.Position));
```

---

If you still want to use multiple appsetings files you could do the following.

In the Startup.cs:

```
        private readonly IConfiguration _configurationName1;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configurationName2;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configurationName1 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettingsWorker1.json")
            .Build();

            _configurationName2 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettingsWorker2.json")
            .Build();
         }
```

Then you can use seperate configurations on demand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've marked as answer but forgot to comment.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring your application, you can define where to get configuration from (see [this blogpost](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/1b2d5b14-ce05-4ef4-a4b9-f9014fc7ccb5.aspx) for instance). Each file could have a section with the settings you want and the individual hosted services could get their relevant configuration by using `configuration.GetSection()`.